# Is it possible to make local HTTP calls in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, rest, blazor-server-side

We are using Blazor Server for our application. Some of our users have intranet rest web api's in their local environment that is not accesible from outside world.

Is it possible to make HTTP calls to their intranet rest web api's from Blazor Server application ? The reason for this, users wants us to integrate invoice data to their service, and if we can make local HTTP calls in client, we want to call their local api to send our invoice data for integration with their system.

Answer (score 1):

When there is line of sight from your Blazor Server backend to these REST APIs then you can call these APIs from the backend. Additionally, when there is line of sight from the user's browser to these REST APIs, you can call these REST APIs from the browser.

What about authentication? How are these REST APIs secured? Are users logging into your web app and are you planning to passthrough the user identity of your web app to these REST APIs?

Comment: I have Azure AD B2C for blazor server app. Users are authenticated. And for some users, they have intranet rest APIs for their accounting software which have it's own authentication mechanism and a known contract/endpoints to use for integration, and users will provide those authentication parameters in my app within their profile info. It's easy to call APIs from server side but in this scenario, server does not have access to that APIs but browser does. And i wonder ways to call them without javascript if it is possible.